# Laravel firstOrNew based on created_at same date

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using lumen. I want to use firstOrNew based on created_at. For example in my table there exists data for created_at = 2021-09-23 14:42:13 . For that cases it will update if request date value become that day. Here I tried with

```
$tableObj = User::firstOrNew([
        'created_at' => Carbon::today() // date('Y-m-d')
    ]);
$tableObj ->mobile= '5457874545';
$tableObj ->save();
```

Here it always inserted new row. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Can You Please Format the date
try

```
 $tableObj = User::firstOrNew([
        'created_at' => Carbon::today()->format('Y-m-d') // date('Y-m-d')
    ]);
$tableObj ->mobile= '5457874545';
$tableObj ->save();
```

**or use UpdateOrCreate method of laravel**

```
  $tableObj = User::updateOrCreate(
               ['created_at' => Carbon::today()->format('Y-m-d')], 
               ['mobile'=>'5457874545']
             );
```

Comment: Thanks for answer . But in created_at it consists datetime which is Y-m-d h:i:s . So, how can I relate with today (Y-m-d)

Comment: Whenever you create or update your record , date will will remain same but your time will change because you set Carbon::today(). So, your date is matched but time will changed it will  create new entry.